# Django - VIew didn't return an HttpResponse Object even though HttpResponse returns

Tags: django, django-views

The error I am getting:

The view report.views.csv_gen_universal didn't return an HttpResponse object.

```
def csv_gen_universal(req):
    if req.POST['csvinputid']:
        # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] ='attachment;filename="M_Wall_report.csv"'
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        content = str(req.POST['csvinputid']).split("^~^")
        for m in content :
            p = m.split("*~*")
            writer.writerow(p)
        return response
    else:
        HttpResponse("Wrong Place")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `return` in your else statement. Your code should be

```
def csv_gen_universal(req):
    if req.POST['csvinputid']:
        # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] ='attachment;filename="M_Wall_report.csv"'
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        content = str(req.POST['csvinputid']).split("^~^")
        for m in content :
            p = m.split("*~*")
            writer.writerow(p)
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Wrong Place")
```